# Issue with refreshing page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Having problem with my angular app, when I refresh page it doesn't show me correct page. It looks like the way I pass parameter to the page is not right.

So I have my state in the ui-router:

```
.state('stateDashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
```

In the page where I have list of Dashboards:

```
<div class="tile" ng-repeat="d in dashList" ng-class="[d.tileColour, d.tileSize]" ui-sref="stateDashboard" ng-click="setDashboard(d.id)">
    <div class="tile-body">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-object">
        <div class="name">
            {{d.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where setDashboard(id) sett id to $rootScope.dashId

and in my controller to display dashboard I have:

```
Dashboards.getDashboard({ id: $rootScope.dashId }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        $rootScope.model = result;
     }
```

So now when I refresh the page $rootScope.dashId is undefined so doesn't display page correctly. How can I fix it?

Comment: where are you getting this dashId from?

Comment: from the dashList, please look on the second code snippet

Comment: Your code doesn't quite match up here.  The HTML is showing `dashList`, which would be `$scope.dashList`.  the JavaScript you posted is referring to `$rootScope.model`.  Not only are you not showing how you get from `$rootScope` to `$scope`, but using `$rootScope` at all is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry I only posted part of the code to simplify it. The html have ng-click="setDashboard(d.id)", which assign id to $rootScope.dashId. As I believe this is incorrect way of passing parameter from 1 controller to the other. That is why I asking for help here.

Comment: You have to pass the dashId as parameter. setDashboard is set On Click. When you refresh or load the new page the rootScope is recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your dashId to the URL so you can pass it when changing dashboard and/or refreshing the page. So avoid calling setDashboard because it will only have effect until you reload the page.

```
.state('stateDashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard/:dashId',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
```

Now inside your controller you can get it like this. No need to use the $rootScope.

```
Dashboards.getDashboard({ id: $stateParams.dashId }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        $rootScope.model = result;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but when I press refresh or just go http://localhost:28422/dashboard/29, I receive lots of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" for all my js files

Comment: That does not seem related. It is a Syntax error, You might have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Well the page works correctly when I direct to it from other page. But only when refresh or go localhost:28422/dashboard/29 it appear with error

Comment: to be even more weird, when I open any of the js file in the Chrome Sources I see html of my page and not the js file

Comment: That is a weird behavior. Did you check that your backend is properly routing '/dashboard/:dashId', to Angular?

Comment: Found the issue, I was using src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", changed to src="../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" and it works now. Many thanks